# What is link_to t() in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I watched Railscast 328 this morning and I am having difficulty finding docs for a method.

```
<%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                  edit_boy_scout_path(boy_scout), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
```

I understand the link_to method, but I am confused about the t('edit .... ) parameter and it is in this method call twice.  An explanation or even pointing me to some docs would be great.  Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `t` function is an alias for `I18n.translate`.

The `default:` option gives the translation to use if the requested key is missing (the `'.edit'` of your example).

See [guide in internationalization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) (and go to 4.1.2 for the syntax of the `:default` option)